# Sending Data to Pusher in laravel broadcast

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am having issues with sending data object to pusher, after saving data to db. When I send the request to to db , it saved to db then initialize the event but it does not send with the specified object.

```
event(new NotifyResponderEvent($emergencyRequest));
```

Here is my code for the event file

```
class NotifyResponderEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $emergencyRequest;


    public function __construct($emergencyRequest)
    {
        $this->$emergencyRequest = $emergencyRequest;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('request');
    }


    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'emergencyRequest';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'data' => [
                $this->emergencyRequest
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

This is what I get in pusher after when the event is fired

```
{
  "emergencyRequest": null
}
```

Even when I log the data before sending its still giving me the same issue, but it is saving on the db and sending to another api that sends sms and some object data as well.

Regards

Comment: hope you added pusher app key in to your .env file. can you share how did you subscribe to the pusher chanel?

Comment: Yes, I've added the pusher key in .env file.. By Pusher channel subscription you are referring to routes/channel file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted ... Not sure what was the problem, I had to delete node_module folder, remove any pusher related packages and reinstall.